# возможно ли в typescript основоваясь на дженерике вернуть тот или иной вариант интерфейса

Tags: typescript

возможно ли реализовать что то такое?

```
export type TD<U = null> = U ? {
  x: number;
} : {
  x?: number;
}
```

в данном случее мне конкретно интересует опциональная (?) зависишая от дженерика (передан или нет)

PC: когда кидал вопрос забыл про Required каторый в принципе решает вопрос, но если есть возможность реализовать вот что то такое, буду рад узнать.

для этого нужно Было.

```
export namespace NCash {
  export interface IInitialState {
    cash: number;
  }
  export type TAdd = Required<IAction<ECashActions.ADD_CASH, IInitialState['cash']>>;
  export type TGet = Required<IAction<ECashActions.GET_CASH, IInitialState['cash']>>;
  export type TActions = TAdd | TGet;
}

export interface IAction<T, U = never> extends Action<T> {
  payload?: U;
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgIgHgKpQLxQHYFcA2OB8aUKEAHsBBgCYDOmuOUA-FAN4BQUUpTAXPQFsARhABOAbnYBfKPw5dS-bMLGSpk9jgjAoAQ37xJAeiNcAek3abtUIQcQBGfMdNQLQA

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасиб) странно вроде помню пробовал(експерементировал) таже не прокотило) кинь как ответ, будь добр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так:

```typescript
type TD<U = null> = U extends null ? {
  x?: number;
} : {
  x: number;
};

let a: TD; // { x?: number | undefined }
let b: TD<1>; // { x: number }
```

Но не очень ясно зачем это нужно.

Comment: обновил вопрос, там кинул для чего надо было( если есть U то и payload, если нет то нет)